# How to implement MSBUILD file tracking feature (Tracker.exe) for a not native VC compiler (GCC) declared in .props files?

Tags: c++, gcc, msbuild, tracking

after searching for hours on the internet I could not find any information or documentation about this. Does anyone know if there is a way to get this done?

Would be great to get a hint to the right direction.

Thanks in advance,

Alex

Answer (score 0):

You have to write task that will use file tracking for incremental build.
.NET API seems is here: [FileTracker Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.utilities.filetracker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

If I were you I’d try to disassemble Microsoft.Build.CPPTasks.Common.dll assembly - class Microsoft.Build.CPPTasks.TrackedVCToolTask to get an idea how it works.

So here’s my off-the-cuff idea how it can works:

1. I think Tracer.exe starts child process (your tool as suspended process).
2. Then it patches kernel32.dll file winapi to track all read and write operation (so I think they patches CreateFile and CloseHandle).
3. Then resumes process
4. After process is finished you should get list of files the child process used.
5. Write file list of input file that were used to produce output file into log file.
6. Second time is yout task invoked you can make optimization in build. Because you have file mapping now you should be able decide if you call your tool for given output or you skip it. You can skip it in case output file time-stamp is newer then all input files and none setting for compilation has changed (project file time-stamp - or something more sophisticated).

[File Tracking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee886424.aspx)